# How to change the content of a text file when I don't have permission to redirect output nor use `sed -i`

Tags: linux, bash, laptop, permissions

I would like to change the brightness on my laptop by changing the content of the file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm on Pop! _OS 18.04, which is essentially Ubuntu 18.04. Gnome 3.

Redirecting `echo` doesn't work, due to permission problems.

```
$ sudo echo "0" > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
zsh: permission denied: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Similarly for `sed -i`, I don't have permission to create a temporary file.

```
$ sudo sed -i -e "s/.+/0/g" /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
sed: couldn't open temporary file /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/sedk0tgUG: Permission denied
```

So what else can I try?

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675759/prevent-sed-from-creating-a-temporary-file. Have you tried `sudo sed -e -i '.....'` note that `-e` comes before `-i`. Or `sudo sed -i '' -e '...'`

Comment: @ChadGorshing `$ sudo sed -e -i "s/.+/0/g" /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` gives 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: \`-'`

Comment: @ChadGorshing `$ sudo sed -i '' -e "s/.+/0/g" /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` gives
`sed: can't read : No such file or directory
sed: couldn't open temporary file /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/sed8jbgJj: Permission denied`

Comment: @ChadGorshing I agree that neither of these makes much sense. I can't explain why they don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way is what comes up in the Ubuntu documentation a lot:  `echo "0" | sudo tee -a /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: Is there a short version for why `tee -a` works where `>` doesn't? Dare I even ask?

Comment: Please, dare. Output redirection is handled by the current shell which runs as an unprivileged user. `sudo tee` makes sure the command that writes to the file is run as root. Doing `sudo echo` just runs the echo command as root, not the redirection.

Comment: Aha, so I would need the equivalent of `echo "0" (sudo >) filename` in order to run the redirect as a privileged user, and since `>` doesn't support this (right?), we need to find a command that does, and `tee` is "the closest thing".

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
sudo su -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
```

or

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
```